# How do I keep my Alpacas inside an enclosure? I'm getting " Cannot rope Alpaca: No enclosed pen"

Tags: rimworld

I'm trying to keep my Alpacas inside an enclosed space. I built a fence area, and a "pen", but I still have 2 problems:

- I don't know how to bind an Alpaca to en enclosed space.
- The Alpaca in the screenshot jumped over the fence. It didn't really work.

How do I keep my Alpacas enclosed?

[image]

**EDIT**

The problem was that the sandbag prevented my enclosure to become an enclosure

[image]

Comment: For the record, proper walls can be used to enclose pens, just not sandbags. You can even make an adjacent building with a door to serve as a barn, for the animals to sleep at night (a must for colder biomes). It's also smart to feed them indoors since food won't deteriorate if placed under a roof (but may still rot if not frozen).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure the area you are trying to use as a pen is actually considered one? Or the Pen Marker you use allows for alpacas in its rules?

Going by your screenshot it looks like 2 visible possibilities: The wall on the bottom is confusing the pen and/or you are missing the fence gate.

I don't know if you have zone highlighting enabled, but if it was and the pen was recognized, it would be showing.

Comment: the problem was indeed that the sandbag wall was preventing the area from becoming an eclosure

Comment: "I don't know if you have zone highlighting enabled" -> I was confused about this. The option "Toggle visibility of zones" does not show pen enclosures. The way to show it is to click on the pen itself.

Comment: Thank you Rapitor